# 'WOULD' usage for present tense when it isn't used in conditionals?

Tags: would, imaginary-situations

- I read *'We use would (’d) / wouldn’t when we imagine a situation or action (= we think of something that is not real)'* this explanation in the book **English Grammar in Use on page no. 72**
- I hear many sentences in movies/series where 'would' is used and they do not seem to be imaginary situations nor are conditional (type 1,3, mixed). they are present tense sentences and I assume them to be imaginary situations and try to understand if they are just unreal/imaginary. 
  Still, I have to re-think about that explanation whenever I see a sentence like that. Is this the way natives understand 'would' sentences or I am doing this wrong?
   The problem is when I use this explanation at the moment and try to understand the situation, it seems that it can't be unreal, it is real what's imaginary in that, I get confused.

examples: 
-> "Picture a scenario where everything would be possible."
-> "Imagine a world where technology would solve all our problems."
-> "In his vision, cars would fly, and buildings would touch the sky."
-> "Close your eyes and think about a day when time would stand still."
-> "She dreamed of a place where laughter would echo in every corner."

- does anybody have any solution for this?

Comment: Please provide at least one example, preferably more, of the type of usage that you have a problem with. Otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: ***I'd*** say we use ***would*** (and ***'d***) in a *range* of contexts. It doesn't always mean the same thing. (And there's nothing 'hypothetical' about the fact that I ***am*** making this claim! :)

Comment: Just think of "conditional **would**" as implying some metaphoric "distance". Either the reference is to something "removed from reality" (hypothetical past / uncertain future), OR the speaker is "distancing" himself from his words (because uncertain, polite, self-effacing, whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - do you recall the celebrated response of Mandy Rice-Davies to counsel's question about something said by Lord Astor?

Comment: *I would like* often means I want, but softer. What you call imaginary is just "I would want another cuppa if you were so kind as to offer, which you have, but only if it's no trouble." In New York, we would say "Yeah, another cup."

Comment: @YosefBaskin  I have added some examples, can you clarify the purpose of using 'would' here? if you'd like to.

Comment: These are all in fact imaginary situations, not happening currently in real life. Look at the verbs of the sentences you have given as an example: to dream, to close your eyes and think, in his vision, imagine, picture. The verbs all create a imaginary situation rather than actual world where things are happening right now.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'd say MRD's *Well, he would say that, wouldn't he?* is in line with *Boys will be boys* - not really "conditional" or "hypothetical" at all (it's *ironic*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I would beg to differ.  It is something we could have predicted. If he were speaking (in such a context or on such a subject), it is something he would say.  Just because it can be delivered with a snarky or ironic tone doesn't change the underlying conditionality.  It is an ad-hoc creation of a hypothetical situation that is based on an actual situation.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice: I'd say you're splitting hairs based on ***syntax***. More to the point, I ***do*** say that! There's nothing "conditional" about my opinion here, even if I couch my words in pointless conventional circumlocution.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So how would you explain **would** then, in "He *would* say that"? Or the **would** in the question I've just asked you?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see **would** there as related to habitual action and inclination *in a given set of circumstances*.  How are you inclined to explain it?

Comment: All the examples added apply to imaginary activities, things that may happen or not. But for the more common polite *would*, adults can't go around saying *Give me chocolate*. So they say *Oh, I would like some, yes*. The extra words *oh*, *would*, and *yes* all wrap the request in terms more neighborly. Oh = Knocking on the door of conversation. Would = possibly, but not as a demand. Yes = clarifying the conclusion, let's have that chocolate.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice: I "explain" my use of ***'d*** in such contexts as reflecting nothing more than force of habit. As before, you seem determined to insist that I should be consciously choosing my verb forms according to a predefined set of possible meanings deriving from formally-defined syntax. But I had no sense of choosing the circumlocutory format in order to express habit OR *specific* circumstances. They're effectively oxymoronic rather than orthogonal alternatives, so if I *did* have one in mind, that should *specifically and noticeably* exclude the other! But I make no such choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  Perhaps I should have asked you "Do you know what you meant?"  So it's a kind of tongue-muscle-memory for you, even when you're typing?

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice: Most people habitually include meaningless "filler" words in all sorts of contexts, and I'm certainly no exception. Just look at how many comments on sites like this start with ***I think...*** Very occasionally, I might write *I **think** X, but I'm not sure* (using typeface to emphasize ***think***), but normally those first two words are effectively "content-free". Pretty much on a par with prefacing *spoken* utterances with ***Ahem, Erm, Well...***  Or my pet bugbear lately - Questions that start with the word ***So*** (having no apparent relevance to what follows! :)